# How to bulk-change a text format?

Tags: nodes, input-formats

I should paste much article content in Drupal in nodes.
The **output data** I paste has much HTML in it.

I need to paste the data without HTML at all so I thought about bulk-changing *the content-type's text format* to "plain text" (rather than Filtered HTML) and then, after I finish pasting all articles, to bulk-change it again, this time to "filtered HTML".

Is that possible to do? Are there any known problems in the process of doing so? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! It depends from how much nodes you need to edit, but I would not change the text format, edit the nodes, and then changing back the text format. Just edit the nodes to remove the HTML markup.

Comment: @apaderno it's about **1,250** nodes !!! I do need some automation here.

Comment: What you outlined won't work - the content is stored raw, and formatted for output. Changing the text format doesn't change the original text/html in the database, just what's displayed

Comment: @alkomosi You are explicitly asking for bulk-changing the text format, but you need to  remove the HTML markup from the nodes you are editing. Changing first the text format isn't necessary. I didn't mean you don't need a way to automate the task.

Comment: Clive and apadermo I get it now. Well, I will try to paste the text without HTML somehow.

Comment: I believe there is no Drupal solution to the problem of pasting much text HTMLized and this question should be deleted.

Comment: I don't recall there is a module that allows you to enter the content of X nodes, removes the HTML markup from that content, and then updates those nodes. You would need to create a custom module for that.